# How to add two possible keys in one keyboard button

Tags: android

I've been trying to create my own android keyboard following [this guide](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/creating-input-method.html) and looking at the [latinIME souce code](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME.git;a=blob;f=res/xml/kbd_qwerty.xml;h=0493b99328d394a873476caf10725addd226a5f8;hb=HEAD).

While reading the kbd_qwerty.xml file I noticed the different tags used and explained [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.Key.html). I was expecting to see certain tag to reproduce what BetterKeyboard application does. They draw more than one key on each button. [Example](http://betterandroid.files.wordpress.com/2009/05/11.png).

Are they adding images or this is somehow possible from the xml?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better Keyboard completely rewrote the onscreen keyboard so they can do what every they want with the layout and key functions.  With the default Android keyboard you'll need to stick with one glyph per key.  Of course you can always use alt's to get other characters.

Comment: CaseyB: It makes sense, but how do you know they rewrote the onscreen keyboard?

Comment: Because there are a lot of features in the BetterKeyboard that aren't possible with the built in Android version.